# Issue when using xquery external variables from the command line in BaseX

Tags: variables, command-line, external, xquery, basex

I have the following query in a XQ file named "consulta.xq"

```
declare namespace xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
declare variable $word as xs:string+ external;

for $entry in doc("cni_es_cushimariano2008")//e 
where $entry//l[matches(., $word)] 
return <e>{$entry//r//text()} --> {$entry//l//text()}</e>
```

My database "cni_es_cushimariano2008" has the following structure/data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dictionary>
<alphabet>aeiobchjmnñprsty</alphabet>
<section id="main" type="standard">
    <!-- cuidarse (de alguien). aamaantsi. -->
    <e>
        <p>
            <l>cuidarse (de alguien)</l>
            <r>aamaantsi<s n="verbo intransitivo"/>
                <s n="infinitivo"/>
            </r>
        </p>
    </e>
    <!-- celoso. aamaantsi. -->
    <e>
        <p>
            <l>celoso</l>
            <r>aamaantsi<s n="adjetivo"/>
            </r>
        </p>
    </e>
    <!-- traer. aamaantsi. -->
    <e>
        <p>
            <l>traer</l>
            <r>aamaantsi<s n="verbo transitivo"/>
                <s n="infinitivo"/>
            </r>
        </p>
    </e>
</section>
</dictionary>
```

I am trying to execute the following command line instruction

```
$ basex -b$word=celoso consulta.xq
```

but I don't receive the expected result and receive the following message:

```
[XPDY0002] No value assigned to $word as xs:string+.
```

I am not an expert using Basex and XQuery so I will be grateful for any answer that might help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` character presumably is interpreted by your command shell, such that `$word` does not reach its destination. It might need to be escaped,

```
$ basex -b\$word=celoso consulta.xq
```

or even omitted,

```
$ basex -bword=celoso consulta.xq
```